# Setting Oracle session variables prior to database read/write events in Entity Framework / ODP.NET

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, dbcontext, odp.net

I have a situation where I need to set oracle session variables/context before read & write events happen (this is a requirement by the client and not negotiable).

Where would be the best place to insert this code?  I'm already overriding the `DBContext.New()` method as well as `DBContext.OnModelCreating()` for other purposes, but I can't tell if either of them are the true beginning of the entire database session (since EF is stateless...?)

Pretty sure the actual code would be a simple `Me.Database.SqlQuery()`, just need to be sure of where to put it.

My perceived options:

## 1

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
    [Other Code]

    MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)

    Me.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SESSIONCOMMAND")
End Sub
```

## 2

```
Using CTX As New MyContext()
    CTX.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SESSIONCOMMAND")

    [OTHER CODE]
End Using
```

## 3

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New(
        New OracleConnection(
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyContext").ConnectionString),
         True)

    Me.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SESSIONCOMMAND")
End Sub
```

I'm pretty sure #3 is not possible because EF opens the connection after this sub, so I can't execute a command against it yet at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing it when the connection state changed from closed to open. Like this...

```cs
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {
        this.Database.Connection.StateChange += Connection_StateChange;
    }

    void Connection_StateChange( object sender, System.Data.StateChangeEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( e.CurrentState == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open )
        {
            if ( sender is System.Data.Common.DbConnection )
            {
                var command = ( sender as System.Data.Common.DbConnection ).CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "SESSIONCOMMAND";
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```